# how can build from API LEVEL 16 to 28?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

unity is 2019.1.9
I  made a game when I do android build  so all is ok but last time in "export build gradle" I received errors.
I have attached this Error  by pic, please see photo and tell, how can I resolve this problem, I always android build from API Level 16 to 28 but I can not build now
why?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error states Unity ads requires a minimum API level of 19. You will either need to remove this package, or change your minimum API level to 19 to be able to build.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings > Other Settings > Minimum API Level. now change this API level to 19 and you are good to go.